# Menu item depend on user articles

Tags: angularjs

in my app I have multiple user rol0 (admin, distributor, buyer). By default, I show 3 menu items. But if the user in his list of articles has `articleAA` i show him the new item in the menu only for this article and another default item. Same, if he has `articleBB` I show him menu item for this article. On login, i chech this and show menu

```
$scope.allArticles = allArticlesFactory.get();
$scope.allArticles.$promise.then(function(data) {

angular.forEach(data, function(key, value){
    switch (key.type){
        case 'articleAA':
            $scope.articleAA= true;
            break;
        case 'articleBB':
            $scope.articleBB= true;
            break;
        default:
        $scope.articleAA= "";
        $scope.articleBB= "";
    }
});
});
})
```

In a menu with `ng-if`, I check value

```
<li ng-if="articleAA === true"><a class="aktivniItem" ui-sref="articleAA">articleAA</a></li>
<li ng-if="articleBB === true"><a class="aktivniItem" ui-sref="articleBB">articleBB</a></li>
```

PROBLEM: when I log in like `admin` I get all menu item and this is ok.
When I log in like a buyer who has `articleAA` and `articleBB` i get all menu items and this is ok. 
But, when I log in like another buyer who doesn't have any of this article, this two menu is still here. When I refresh, this special menu item disappears.

I try on top of controller put

```
$scope.articleAA= "";
$scope.articleBB= "";
```

and also

```
$scope.articleAA= false;
$scope.articleBB= false;
```

But, same problem is here. Next user always get menu from previous user, but if he refresh, everything is ok.

default menu
`| Home | Articles | Info |`

if user have articleAA
`| Home | Articles | Info | ArticleAA |`

if user have articleBB
`| Home | Articles | Info | ArticleBB |`

if user have articleAA and articleBB
`| Home | Articles | Info | ArticleAA | ArticleBB |`
Thnx

Comment: did you try waiting a couple minutes before it hides? on a user with no privilege on `articleAA` and `articleBB`

Comment: yes, I try... for now I move this in login function and it working... but I know this is a workaround, I try to find better solution